# SteamAPI_Init() failed. Refer to Valve's documentation or the comment above this line for more information. | Steamworks.NET

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, steamworks-api

> [Steamworks.Net] SteamAPI_Init() failed. Refer to Valve's documentation or the comment above this line for more information.

It works fine in the Unity editor, but somehow I get an error with something built for Windows.
The code is below. Very simple.

```
    if (SteamManager.Initialized)
    {
        string playerName = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();
        Debug.Log(playerName);
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
```

My username appears in debug in the editor. However, the build closes the app.

My app has not been published yet and I have not submitted any builds.
But, the fact that the editor can identify the user maybe means that something went wrong during the build process.

I created a `steam_appid.txt` at the root of the project and entered the AppID.

What's the difference between playing in the editor and playing a build?

Someone teach me please. Thank you.   (Google Translated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I submitted the build to Steamworks and installed it on Steam, I got no errors.

But uploading a build every time is very tedious...

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by placing the `steam_appid.txt` (containing the steam app id) next to the exported/built exe file

Answer (score 0):

In your editor Unity. You must make sure:

- App ID in the root folder(Asset(Not include inside Assets),,...,steam_appid.txt) config true with your app id created on a partner.
- The steam app must run with runtime editor launching to confirm init.

--
I think your config and setup have error process. So I recommend you read more on 2 repositories:
https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET
https://github.com/Facepunch/Facepunch.Steamworks